# How do I add more Contrast after ColorRamp Node?

Tags: materials

I am trying to get the perfect noise pattern to displace my object.  I have the overall shape of it right, but I need the grays to turn black and the light grays to turn white.

I've got it as contrast-y as possible with one ColorRamp Node, but it's still too gray. When I add a second ColorRamp node to push the contrast a little further, nothing happens.

A) Why does the second ColorRamp have no effect?

B) What can I do to increase the contrast?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2gni3vgm11kh7c/Add%20Contrast%20After%20Colorramp.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: You might try RGBCurves instead of color ramp

Comment: Or try a different interpolation other than Linear on the ramp, and remember you can add more stops

Comment: but it's all relative anyway, I guess, if you need more displacement you can use the Scale value on the displacement node.  Can you be more specific about what you need?  (part of the problem might be this difference operation producing some negative values which are operated upon strangely by color ramp, but that's just a thought, I have no idea)

Comment: Also, I tried that texture (even without the contrast boost) as the basis for displacement, and even set to .005 scale, it's pretty strong/messy, even on a plane subdivided 100 times with a Subdivision surface modifier level 5 on top of that. Is there some reason you're using this detailed of a texture for displacement? Could the same be done a different way?

Comment: *"A) Why does the second ColorRamp have no effect?"* - because the 1st ColorRamp outputs either black or white, which translate to either 0 or 1, which end up being black and white on the 2nd Color Ramp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your *View Transform* from *Filmic* to *Standard* and/or increase the *Emission Strength*:

[image: Cont]

Attempt #2 - forget the emission (so use material preview mode to see it), remove the (very small) subsurface value, and multiply the result by 4 or so:

[image: Cont2]

Attempt #3 - Use a Map Range node to expand the range, and therefore the contrast:

[image: Range]

Comment: Hey man, thanks for weighing in.  I can't simply increase the Emission though, I'm just using it for preview purposes, because this is meant to be a displacement texture.  Same story for Filmic vs. Standard.  Is there a way to bring out the contrast with nodes?

Comment: I added a second suggestion, try that one.

Comment: Hey, appreciate the second attempt! Sadly that's not an option either, as a multiply will left all the values.  Since there are no blacks all the grays get brighter.  Contrast will spread the whites away from the blacks, from the middle gray value, so I would love to know if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Hey man, I figured out how to do it using a Map Range node.  Your suggestion to use a Math node made me realize that there are other ways to create contrast outside the box of my normal thinking.  So I credit you for the answer if you want to edit your post I'll mark it as answered. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, I added it to my answer.